# Is posible get price Token using uniswap v3 way contract read?

Tags: solidity, ethers.js

I know that in SushiSwap it is possible to obtain the price of a token with a tight contract reading **getAmountsOut** and then send it to the from through the etherjs library.
https://etherscan.io/address/0xd9e1ce17f2641f24ae83637ab66a2cca9c378b9f#readContract

It is possible to do the same with the v3 version of **Uniswap V3**?
https://docs.uniswap.org/protocol/introduction

Or is possible e another method?

Answer (score 2):

You can use getOutputAmount from:
[pool - getOutputAmount](https://github.com/Uniswap/v3-sdk/blob/545fb4eb9003cd20c185fdd62949008695283012/src/entities/pool.ts)

Example how to use:
https://github.com/Uniswap/v3-sdk/issues/78